# There is a pop-up showing “Timed out waiting for launcher to connect” in vscode while running python file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
The below is my Launch.json file:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Could someone please help with this?
Not sure why i am getting this error.
I ran the code in an online python compiler where it worked fine.
So i can say that there is no error in the code.
Still not sure why the pop up is showing up suddenly.

All help are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the extension? And how long does it normally take for this code to start executing?

Comment: its just a small code it runs within a few seconds. it runs fine for a couple of times. After running for around 5-6 times i get to see this pop up. I'm not quite sure about the extension

Comment: you can compare what you have installed to what is listed at https://aka.ms/pvsc-marketplace to make sure you have the latest version. If you do then I would open a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy.

Answer (score 0):

check your version of python in the bottom left of vs code and make sure it is supported by the vs code python extension